# jQuery - Best practice when returning content from getJson request to caller function

Tags: jquery, getjson, jquery-callback

What is the best practice when returning content from the result of a `$.getJson` request to a caller function? 
I have a function called `$.fn.getSomeData` which has a `$.getJson` call inside it (this function is in a JS file which JSP's wanting to use my webservice must import).

Then inside the calling JSP a function will call my `$.fn.getSomeData` function.

Because my `$.getjson` request is asynchronous I have to wait for the callback function to execute before i can think about processing the JSON. What is the best way to handle passind the resulting data back to the function in the calling JSP.

Other options i have read including passing a Div into the `$.fn.getSomeData` method and then in the $.getJson callback function I would do processing of the json and append to the Div as I want it to appears.

A second option was to pass a function into `$.fn.getSomeData`. This function can then be called in the `$.getjson` callback function.

Can someone recommend a best practice? I would prefer not to use the option of passing the Div into my `$.fn.getSomeData` function as i want to reduce coupling in my external JS file.

Also is there a way to add a callback function to the call I make from the JSP to `$.fn.getSomeData` that would somehow trigger once the `$.getjson` callback has executed?

Looking forward to hearing your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd version is what you want.

Pass in the function that you want to be executed when the getJson request completes.

```
$.fn.getSomeData = function(callback) {
    $.getJSON('url', data, callback);
}

$('div').getSomeData(function() { 
    // do something
});
```

To process the data first and then call the function do this:

```
$.fn.getSomeData = function(callback) {
    $.getJSON('url', data, function(result) {
        // do something with data
        callback(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do some processing of the resulting json first and then pass the modified json on to the function passed in?